# Adding files to be used by #includes

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm starting with a new Win32 console app project in Visual Studio 2010.  I am setting up my environment to support beginner level OpenGL programs.  I am in the process of adding required *.cpp files and *.h files.  I added

`#include "../../shared/gltools.h"//opengl toolkit`

Error "cannot open source file" is displayed when I hover over `#include`.  I attempted to add the required file.  I right click Source files and choose > Add > New Filter > called it shared and hit enter.

What is a filter?  I thought I would be adding a physical folder rather than a filter.  How does this differ from "External Dependencies"?

Comment: at least tell what IDE are you using...

Comment: This is too much out of context.

Comment: @DesmondHume - This project is practically empty outside of adding references and converting back to the generic entry point (rather than t_main).  I'm a pro C# developer.  So working through C# goggles is probably the source of my confusion.  What else do you need to know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the project properties, unde **Compiler**, find the field **Additional Include Directories** and add the directory where the file is located, or, alternatively, the directory where `/shared/` is located.

Answer (score 0):

find and analyse some of the OpenGL samples, these are most often with OpenGL headers and libraries which clearly you have. Check which include directory you are using - configure that as 'Luchian Grigore' above described. When you have that working (program compiles) remember to add library directories (in project settings, linker options) or there will be linker problems. This all should be described in howto or code samples. Analyse them to get started. Don't reinvert the wheel and have fun.